# Bot replying to a message from a specific user - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

Only the specific user and the specific word can the bot input

```
example:
THE SPECIFIC USER : User1
THE SPECIFIC WORD : PASSCODE
-----------------------
User1: Hello (didn't input)
User2: PASSCODE (didn't input)
User1: PASSCODE (input)
BOT  : RESPOND
```

Answer (score 1):

Join our discord server to help us create discord.py bots!
https://discord.gg/Nte4DseR

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='YOUR PREFIX')

guild = client.get_guild('GUILD ID')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    user = client.get_user('MEMBER ID')

    if message.author == client.user:

        return

    if message.author == user:

        if message.content == 'PASSCODE':

            await message.channel.send('RESPOND')

client.run('SERVER ID')
```

Comment: I up voted your message thinking that this could be used in the future

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the ID must not be between "...", '...'
Just the numbers!

Example:

```
if message.author.id == 000000000000000000 and message.content.upper() == 'PASSCODE':
    await message.channel.send('RESPOND')
```